# Estoy intentando hacer una ruta dinamica en Nextjs, pero no puedo,¿Como soluciono este problema?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Estoy aprendiendo nextjs y me propuse a hacer una ruta dinamica usando una pokeapi, la api se consume sin problemas, lo que queria hacer era una lista de cartas de pokemon(que ya esta hecha) y que al hacerle click a cualquier pokemon lleve al usuario a la ruta dinamica.

Para hacer estas rutas dinamicas uso el hook **useRouter** *(me estoy apoyando en un video de udemy, en donde el sujeto usa next version 12 por eso el useRouter, aunque por supuesto revise la documentacion actualizada: next13, ya que es la version que uso)*, segun yo, creo que aun es valido este hook en esta version en base a su documentacion: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/use-router.

Este es el componente de la ruta dinamica, **PokemonPage** esta dentro de src/app/pokedex/[id].jsx

```
 'use client'
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"
import Layout from "../../../layouts/Layout"

export default function PokemonPage(){
  const router = useRouter
  console.log(router)

  return(<>
  <Layout>
    <h1>Esta es la pgina con ruta dinamica </h1>
  </Layout>
  </>)
}
```

Este es el componente que consume el api y renderiza la lista de pokemon (no van a ver el api porque esta en otro componente, estos consumen el api mediante el parametro **pokemon**):

```
'use client';
import Image from "next/image";
import styles from "../styles/ListOfPost.module.css";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function PokemonCard({ pokemon }) {
  const router = useRouter()

  return (
    <>
      <li key={pokemon.id} className={styles.className__carta__lista} >
        <div className={styles.className__carta__contenedor} onClick={() => router.push(`/pokedex/${pokemon.id}`)}>
          <div className={styles.className__carta__contenedor__p}>
            <Image
              src={pokemon.img}
              alt="pokemon"
              width={200}
              height={200}
              className={styles.className__carta__img}
            />
            <h4 className={styles.className__carta__name}>{pokemon.name}</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </>
  );
}
```

Al intentar ejecutar estos codigos, la pantalla se torna totalmente en blanco, no se muestra absolutamente nada.
El error de consola del visual studio code arroja esto:

> error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
> at JSON.parse ()

Sin embargo este error la ultima vez me lo tiro por usar algo que en la version next13 ya no se usa. El mensaje del error no arroja un dato realmente util, de hecho no tiene sentido.

En **rojo** esta todo lo relacionado al hook **useRouter**

[image: Componente pokemonCard.jsx]

[image: Componente Pokedex/[id].jsx]

¿Como puedo solucionar esto?, solo quiero hacer una ruta dinamica.

Comment: Dando una revisión general, parece que en el componente `PokemonPage` falta llamar al hook `useRoute`, en este momento solo se pasa su referencia:  `const router = useRouter`, pero debería ser llamado `const router = useRouter()` es decir faltan los parentesis.

Comment: Hola, lo cambie pero no pasa nada. Parece ser que una mejor manera de hacer esto es: 
import Layout from "../../../../layouts/Layout"

export default function PokemonPage({params}){
  const {id} = params

  return(<>
  <Layout>
    <h1>Esta es la pgina con ruta dinamica </h1>
  </Layout>
  </>)
}

Comment: De hecho el problema aun persiste, pero en internet parece ser que es la forma mas 'reciente' de hacerlo, aun asi sigue sin funcionar, sigo bastante perdido.

Comment: Sugiero eliminar el folder `src`, dejando el directorio `app` a nivel de root, avisanos del resultado, asegurate de corregir esto también `const router = useRouter`por `const router = useRouter()`